# netinet/sctp.h: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, gcc, sctp

I'm unable to include  in any of my files. It always fails during compilation.
I got the lksctp-tools package installed.

I run

```
     gcc -Wall -lsctp -o client admin.c deserializer.c input_parser.c main.c receive_response.c send_request.c serializer.c utils.c
```

And I get:

```
main.c:2:10: fatal error: netinet/sctp.h: No such file or directory
#include <netinet/sctp.h>
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I'm using Fedora, I don't know if that changes anything. 
However the project seems to work fine on CLion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok turns out I had to do the following:

```
yum install lksctp-tools-dev
```

Answer (score 14):

On ubuntu need to install `libsctp-dev`.

```
sudo apt install libsctp-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

For Amazon Linux 2:

```
yum -y install lksctp-tools-devel
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).